# How to change git repository using cloud 9

Tags: git, github, cloud9-ide, cloud9

I cloned a github repository using the commands

```
git config --global user.name "x"
git config --global user.email x
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "message"
git remote add origin /link/
git push -u origin master
```

now I am in the workspace and want to connect the workspace to a different GitHub repository. How to do that ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: You can add more remotes or change the default `origin` remote to point to a different remote, but you generally won't want to change your repository to go to an *unrelated* remote repository. If you want to work on completely different set of code, create a new folder and `clone` or `init` (FYI, what you did is not `clone`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you have already connected to a github reop

, you need to remove the a remote **first**,

**Removing a remote**
Use the git remote `rm` command to remove a remote URL from your repository.

The git remote rm command takes one argument:
A remote name, for example, destination:

```
$git remote -v
# View current remotes
origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (push)
destination  https://github.com/FORKER/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
destination  https://github.com/FORKER/REPOSITORY.git (push)
$git remote rm destination
# Remove remote
$git remote -v
# Verify it's gone
origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

**Note**: git remote rm does not delete the remote repository from the server. It simply removes the remote and its references from your local repository.

Second, I git init new repository.

Hope it helps